# Regular points and preimage theorem.

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Is there some other way to think about this? Here is the statement of the problem.

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth map. Now to show $f^{-1}(0)$ is a sub manifold in the context of the Preimage theorem, we need to show that $0$ is a regular value.

So upon computing the Jacobian $J(f)(x_o, \dots, x_n)$, what usually is done is to find all points $J(f)(x_0, \dots,x_n) \neq 0$ and that shows $(x_0, \dots, x_n)$ is not a critical point, hence it is a regular point. Sometimes this definition is given in the opposite and we say $q$ is a regular point if $J(f)(q)$ is surjective.

Now under that definition, usually arguments say that $J(f)(q)$ is surjective if and only if $J(f)(q) \neq 0$. Doesn't setting a matrix to $0$ only find points where the full rank isn't $0$? How does that show all points $p$ such that the Jacobian $J(f)(p)$ will have full rank $1$? Oh ranks are determined by integers, right because if it isn't $0$, it is $1$. Doesn't this method fail if $J(f)$ is an $n \times m$ matrix? How does this work under the definition that "regular points are points where derivatives are surjective?". The entries in the matrix are arbitrary values.

Note that if we use the definition that regular points are not critical points, I believe we have to do the second-derivative test for if $J(f)$ is a square matrix.

Answer (score 0):

A rough sketch.

- In the context of this theorem $S = f^{-1}(0)$ and $D_xf \not = 0$ for all $x \in S$. Letting $f = f(x^1,...,x^n)$ then one of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}(x) \not = 0$.
- Without loss of generality, we may assume it is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^n}(x)$ . Otherwise we just reparametrize. We will now write $f = f(u,v)$ where $u$ is in place of $x^1,...,x^{n-1}$ and $v$ in place of $x^n$.
- Applying the Implicit Function theorem, we have the existence of a differentiable function $g$ such that $f(u,v) = f(u,g(u))$ for some neighborhood of $u$.
- If we define the map $\phi_x(u) = (u, g(u))$ then its differentiable and so is it's inverse $\phi^{-1}_x(u,v) = u$.
- Hence $\phi_x$ exists for each $x \in S$ and they are diffeomorphisms from $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ to $S$.